# How to list available audio i/o devices in Bash

Tags: macos, audio, terminal, device

Is there a Terminal command I can use to list available audio devices on my Mac, running osx???  I've had no luck with (arecord -l) | (aplay -l).

Thanks in advance. Hopefully this isn't a repeat question, although I've been searching far and wide...

Dan

Comment: No `arecord` and `aplay` because MacOSX isn't using ALSA.  Also worth noting that unlike Linux and other more traditional *NICES device driver on MacOSX don't always expose their interfaces through a psuedo-filesystem such as `/dev` (or `/sys` on Linux).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess the best you can do is typing `system_profiler SPAudioDataType`, then you can format the output with sed/grep/awk. It's what I do when I want to list USB devices in osx, for example.